# How to exit multiple nested shells at once?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

I have a host on which I don't have sudo. Its been setup with ksh, I'm too used to bash and chsh doesn't work. So I put in a /bin/bash as the first line in the .profile on the system.

So the result is, when I login to this system, it automatically gets me into bash. However, when I exit the shell, not suprisingly I land up in ksh.

Any tricks to avoid this?

Answer (score 8):

Use `exec` to replace the current process (shell) with the new process (shell).

Comment: More specifically, use `exec` to launch your bash from your .profile so there is no ksh left.  (the initial wording made it sound like `exec` would exit both shells at once)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend two steps:

```
if [ $SHELL != /bin/bash ]
then SHELL=/bin/bash exec /bin/bash --login
fi
```

Or, you can compress that to:

```
[ $SHELL != /bin/bash ] && SHELL=/bin/bash exec /bin/bash --login
```

You can then put the rest of your Bash profile after this.  Note that probably you don't put a shebang on the first line - that will confuse things.  Also, while testing, make sure you have a second connection (window) open so that you can adjust problems.  It is annoying to get locked out by an erroneous profile.

Answer (score 0):

You may write a script named `myexit` like this:

```
kill  -1 $(ps | sed 1d | awk '{print $1}')
```

It sends the signal hang up (SIGHUP) to process attached to this terminal.
And would not affect any process started up by nohup.

Comment: `kill -1 $(ps -t $(tty) o pid=)` or `kill -1 $(ps | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}')`